# Redis keeps disconnecting and connecting in expressJS from AWS Elasticache

Tags: node.js, express, redis, amazon-elasticache

I am trying to connect redis in my application in expressJs, it is working on localhost but not when i use my redisurl from AWS ElastiCache.

Here is my code.
Redis.js

```
const redis = require('redis');
require('dotenv').config();   

const client = redis.createClient( { url: process.env.REDIS_URL } ); 

client.on('connect', () => { console.log('Connected to Redis'); });  

(async () => { await client.connect(); })();  

client.on('error', (err) => { console.error("Redis Error: ${err}"); });  

client.on('reconnecting', () => console.log('client is reconnecting'));  

client.on('ready', () => console.log('client is ready'));

module.exports = client;
```

Here is my Error

```
Redis Error: Error: Connection timeout
client is reconnecting 
Redis Error: Error: Connection timeout 
client is reconnecting 
Redis Error: Error: Connection timeout client is reconnecting
```

This keeps on repeating.

I tried using host and url as parameters of `redis.createClient()`

Redis version 4.6.x
Node Version 18
Express version 4.18.x

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you don't need a username and password to connect to your **Redis** instance on **AWS ElastiCache**.
If required, provide the username and password options in the `createClient` options:

```
const client = redis.createClient({
  host: 'your-redis-cluster-name.xxxxxx.ng.0001.use1.cache.amazonaws.com',
  port: 6379,
});
```

Comment: This did not work, i tried, basically on local after adding these details i get redis connected as it doesnot even use the host and port that i gave as parameter in options and use localhost instead. In vercel it gives an error `ERROR   Redis Error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379`